# Does the synthesized destructor destroy the memory allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class without a destructor and a constructor like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : p(new int(a)) {}

private:
    int *p;
};
```

```
{
    Foo a(4);
}
```

After this block of code will the memory allocated on the heap be released ?
Or do i have to explicitly provide a destructor like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) : p(new int(a)) {}
    ~Foo();

private:
    int *p;
};

Foo::~Foo() {
    delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any memory we allocate on the heap using `new` **must** always be freed by using the keyword `delete`.

So,you have to **explicitly** free the memory allocated by `new` on the heap using the keyword `delete` as you did in the destructor. The synthesized destructor will not do it for you.

Note if you don't want to deal with memory management by yourself then you can use **smart pointers**. That way you will not have to use `delete` explicitly by yourself because the destructor corresponding to the smart pointer will take care of freeing up the memory. This essentially means if the data member named `p` was a smart pointer instead of a normal(built in) pointer, then you **don't** have to write `delete p` in the destructor of your class `Foo`.

Comment: The word "must" is a little too strong here.  If you use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<int>` instead of `int *` the pointer will be automatically deleted by the synthesized destructor.

Comment: But when the class is changed to use `std::shared_ptr<int> p;` the compiler-generated destructor will free the memory. And the compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator will work correctly. +1.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional answer to Anoop's correct one:

Just try to "emphasize" with the compiler and the runtime. If the destructor call occurs, how should the environment decide whether to call `delete` on a pointer or not? It has no chance to determine this and it's actually not its job by language design (partially in contrast to the C# and Java philosophy). The pointer could be a **non-owning one** as well, whose referred dynamically allocated storage should survive your particular destructor call, even possible for cases where your class was the allocator (bad design in general but allowed).

The destructor context just "sees" the members and for this case, that's solely a pointer a priori, not a possibly further dynamically allocated ressource.
Please try to get familiar with the important [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) -technique, that is not only relevant to dynamic memory allocation.